# AdMob response in Russian Federation

Tags: android, admob

As we know since 2022 AdMob stopped working in Russian Federation. I am not there and don't have an option to go there to test, but I want to know what errors / callbacks are being called when app initializes AdMob SDK in Russia or when it tries to show ads and fails due to sanctions.

Basically I'm expecting either some sort of InitializationStatus:

```
MobileAds.initialize(activity, initializationStatus -> {   ???   });
```

Or, it might be that `onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError)` is being called.

I'm really curious about what happens there - the details of `initializationStatus` or `loadAdError`, and how can I understand from code that app is under sanctions and AdMob is not working there. Would appreciate any help from people who can test/debug the AdMob SDK in Russia and write the result.

Or, if someone knows how this could be tested reliably from outside Russia, would appreciate that information too.

Note: Tried to change location from emulator, but AdMob is working and showing ads.